# How to use the new GPU accelerated avd?

Tags: android, emulation, gpu, android-virtual-device, hardware-acceleration

Google has announced that the Android emulator finally uses the GPU, as written [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html)

However, I can't find a tutorial of how to use it. I've tried to do some things and it just keeps crashing.

So far , I've tried to :

1. Install the app on "...\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\IntelHaxm.exe".

   2. Enable/disable the flag on GPU emulation for the avd.
   3. Restart eclipse and OS .

Is there anyone who have succeeded working with the new feature?

Comment: From what I can see - I did steps you've done, and 4.0.3 runs smoother than previous versions(right after sdk tools for 4.x were released, I was even unble to load it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The GPU emulation doesn't work very well at the moment:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28531
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28529
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28563

I also didn't manage to run it due to the crash.

A simple instruction of how to turn it on can be found here:
https://plus.google.com/108967384991768947849/posts/DSi3oAuNnS7

Comment: since i can't vote for both you and "skogge" , i choose your answer to fit as the answer .that's because you also mention that i'm not the only one who can't run the emulator

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of different ways to turn on GPU acceleration described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#acceleration

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Android VM , it's quite a great alternative to get a hardware accelerated emulator : http://androvm.org/blog/.

Comment: how do i use it ? do i have to use virtualBox for it? they also have a special exe file which i can't understand what it's used for.